# iPad portrait app loads iAd in Landscape mode

Tags: xcode, iad, simulator, landscape-portrait, adbannerview

I have a universal device app with Device Orientation in Portrait and Upside Down. For iPad Storyboard I clicked orientation to be Portrait as well. When I click on the iAd in iPad simulator, the app flips to landscape mode. When I close the iAd, the app automatically turns back to portrait mode like normal. I've looked at a few possible solutions on this site and they didn't work for me. How to fix this issue?

```
 #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods


-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[banner setAlpha:1];

[UIView commitAnimations];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set didautorotate to NO and supportedOrientations to maskPotrait only in the viewcontroller that presents iAD view

Comment: You mean the following?...

       - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    
          return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |           UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
    
              }

This doesn't work. Where do i set didautorotate?